# Filter file array based on the file extensions

Tags: android, android-file

I have the following code:

```
File dir = new File("/sdcard/LOST.DIR");
final File file[]=dir.listFiles();
```

And the file[] array here contains a list of all the files present in the dir.
I want to create another file[] array based on file extensions. Ex: this new array should contain the list of all image files only (ending with .jpg / .png / .tif etc) and it should exclude other files.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to find files:

```
public void processDirectory(File aFile)
{
   if (aFile.isFile()) 
   {
       processFile(aFile);
   } else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {            
   File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
   if (listOfFiles != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
         processDirectory(listOfFiles[i]);
   } else {
      Log.d(TAG, " [ACCESS DENIED]");
   }
}
}

public void processFile(File aFile) 
{
try 
{
if (!aFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
return;
//Add file path to another array of files
}
}
```

and now you can do like this:

```
File dir = new File("/sdcard/LOST.DIR");
processDirectory(dir)
```

**UPDATE:** for example you can declare

```
ArrayList<String> = filesPath new ArrayList<String>();
```

and in processFile:

```
filesPath.Add(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

and at the end you can get array like this:

```
filesPath.toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The only thing I have a doubt on currently is in the processFile(File aFile) method, how do I add file path to another array of files?  .          File f[]; for(i=0;i<file.length.i++) { f[i] = aFile; } this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this. It may help filter files with provided extensions:

```
import java.io.*;
abstract class Test implements FileFilter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        final String[] okFileExtension = new String[]{"jpg","png","gif","pdf"};
        File name[] = f.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File file){
                for(String extension : okFileExtension){
                    if(file.getName().endsWith(extension))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Java File methods` for this, (I never try this)

```
 File[] listFiles(FileFilter filter)
```

Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter.

```
File[] listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)
```

Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter.

Look at this nice JAVA File Filter example [Filter Files in Java](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/FilterFiles.shtml)